# MSACCESS 97 Efail on Query using vb.net in Legacy System

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, ms-access

When I run the following query from .net it comes up with  a efail error
[image]

But when I run the sql script threw access it is successfully this is a legacy system by the way im supporting it said on-line that it was reserved words but i cant see any in this query as size and all are prefixed ?

```
SELECT 
    Orders.OrderNumber, 
    Orders.OrderLine, 
    Orders.Orderdate, 
    Orders.Deldate, 
    Orders.CutOffDate, 
    detail.Location, 
    Location.Description,   
    TagBarCode.TagBcode, 
    detail.PLU, 
    Style.Description, 
    StockType.Description,
    VatRate.Vcode, 
    VatRate.Vatname, 
    VatRate.VatRate, 
    Orders.OnOrder, 
    Sum(Orders.Cost*Orders.Onorder) AS LineNetCost, 
    Orders.Cost, 
    Sum(orders.cost*(1+(VatRate.VatRate/100))) as GrossCost
FROM (
 (
  (
    (
      (Style INNER JOIN detail ON Style.uniqueref = detail.UniqueRef)
      INNER JOIN Orders ON (Orders.PLU = detail.RootPlu) 
                       AND (Style.uniqueref = Orders.UniqueRef) 
                       AND (detail.Size = Orders.Size) 
                       AND (detail.Location = Orders.Location)
    ) 
    INNER JOIN StockType ON detail.Stocktype = StockType.Stocktype
   ) 
   INNER JOIN Location ON detail.Location = Location.Location
  ) 
  INNER JOIN TagBarCode ON (detail.RootPlu = TagBarCode.Plu) AND (detail.Size = TagBarCode.Size)
 ) 
 INNER JOIN VatRate ON detail.VCode = VatRate.Vcode
GROUP BY 
    Orders.OrderNumber, 
    Orders.OrderLine, 
    Orders.Orderdate, 
    Orders.Deldate, 
    Orders.CutOffDate, 
    detail.Location, 
    Location.Description, 
    TagBarCode.TagBcode, 
    detail.PLU, 
    Style.Description, 
    Orders.OnOrder, 
    StockType.Description, 
    VatRate.Vcode, 
    VatRate.Vatname, 
    VatRate.VatRate, 
    orders.cost;
```

Comment: I think it might be the size field but its only used in joins it doesnt appear in the select clause

Answer (score 0):

Apparently You need to do it like this [Location].[Description] as description is a reserved word